# What or which one

Tags: what

I have the following question: Is it gramatically correct to say: 'What is your favourite one?' when speaking about favourite flavour of ice cream in general.

A: What is your favourite flavour of ice cream?
B: I have a lot of favourite ones.
C: OK, but what exactly is your favourite one?

Comment: There's nothing _ungrammatical_ about it, but I think most people would use _which_.

Answer (score 2):

Swan in *Practical English Usage* (p622) says:

> *Which* and *what* are often both possible, with little difference of meaning.
>
> - Which/what is the hottest city in the world?

But he then notes:

> We prefer *which* when we have a limited number of choices in mind.
>
> - We've got white or brown bread. Which will you have?

I would add a further example from the nursery rhyme about the fish:

- Which finger did it bite?

*Which* is certainly the better choice here.

What Swan does not mention, however, is that  *What is...* can be contracted (→ *What's...*), whereas *Which is...* cannot. For this reason, I suspect that *What's...?* is the more common choice in spoken language, notwithstanding Swan's second point above.

"*What's...* has also recently become much more common in written language, despite the necessity to search for the apostrophe on the keyboard. The nGram link shows a comparison of *What's your favorite...* and *Which is your favorite...*.

[What's your favorite / Which is your favourite](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What%27s+your+favorite%2CWhich+is+your+favorite&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWhat%20%27s%20your%20favorite%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWhich%20is%20your%20favorite%3B%2Cc0) *

Since there is a potentially infinite number of ice-cream flavours, I think "*What's your favorite ice-cream?*" is fine for an out-of-the blue question.

But if you are standing in front of a rack with 5 different flavours in an Eiscafe , then "*Which is your favorite ice-cream?*   seems somewhat preferable.

And it also seems preferable in the context of asking Person B to specify which is the absolute favourite among the limited number of favourites they are referring to.

---

* Note: The nGram comparison works if you type in the strings directly, but the link above does not - presumably because of the apostrophe. I'd be grateful for advice on how to fix this problem.